# What are the minimal screen parameters for tablet bought for reading papers

Tags: publications, reading

Kind of related to my last question: [Is typical ebook reader with pdf support enough to read scientific papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2239/is-typical-ebook-reader-with-pdf-support-enough-to-read-scientific-papers) (but I guess that this is distict enough).

What are minimal sreeen parameters for tablet so I can read papers with ease:

- is 7'' screen size enough, or do I need 10''? I figured out that 5'' is not enough (to much scrolling).
- Is getting additional 3'' (from 7'' to 10'') worth about 70% price increase?
- is iPad's retina display (2048 x 1536) really usefull or I can stick to cheaper tablets?

Comment: Like @scientifics says, you should really go try these devices out yourself to see what you prefer. I find 7" is fine with zoom on my Kindle Fire. Also, I can't possibly imagine Retina Display being worth it just for reading papers...

Comment: Alas if I was living in a civilized counrty interacting witch such device before purchase would be easy, yet in Barbaric country I come from only place I can get to touch these devices are telecoms saloons (and I managed to download an example paper only in Galaxy Tab 7, rest had internet disabled).

Comment: Aaah, that is a problem. Well this youtube video might help for the Fire, and there are certainly similar videos for other devices: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGv3BszDzU4

Comment: Also, I find that if you turn the tablet so that it's in "landscape" orientation, the text size of math pdfs is the same as on paper. So then you simply have to scroll up and down each page. [I swear I don't work for Amazon! I just love my Kindle Fire!]

Comment: What field of research are you in? If papers are text only, probably anything is good enough. Large diagrams or pictures? 7'' probably won't cut it - you probably want something similar in size to the paper it would be printed on.

Answer (score 1):

The screen size really depends on how much scrolling/zooming you want to do...I would suggest trying both the 7" and 10" out in person.

As for the retina display, text is going to be much sharper. Again, I would check this out in person.